# Сохранение целого числа

Tags: c, битовые-операции

Как сохранить целое число в 8-ми разрядную переменную? Допустим сохранить число 511 как 255.

Comment: Присвоением :) А в чем проблема? Или вы хотите сохранить в одном байте значение, превышающее предельно допустимое?..

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы.

Comment: Если **только хранить** - ну, write only - то без проблем! `unsigned char с; int i = 511; с = i;` и плюнуть на предупреждения компилятора. Вот только потом не нужно его читать. P.S. Скажите мне, как мужик мужику - вы никогда поллитру в 200-грамовый стакан не пробовали наливать так, чтоб она там целиком поместилась?...

Comment: 511 в двоичном виде 1 1111 1111, а нужно сохранить только первые 8 бит (1111 1111 = 255). Так же нужно чтобы с полученным числом можно было работать с побитовыми операциями

Comment: А 510 должно сохраниться как 254, а 256 - как 0?

Comment: вот мое задание: "На вход программе подается целое число n. Его требуется сохранить в 8-ми разрядную переменную.
Программа должна посчитать и вывести на экран количество бит числа n, установленных в ноль". Я понимаю как сделать это без сохранения в 8-ми разрядную переменную, но мне интересно как правильно сделать это задание

Comment: Задание ничего не говорит от обрезке слишком больших чисел, оно просто подразумевает, что введённое значение вмещается в диапазон 0..255. Не плодите сущности сверх необходимого минимума.

Comment: Чем препод тупее, тем более его задания заковыристы и оторваны от жизни

Comment: @Pavel Gridin Да просто человек представляет себе, что введут 6 или 15, и на этом останавливается. Заковыристых юзеров он не видел :)  Впрочем, в программе можно явно указать "введите число не более 255"

Answer (score 3):

> 511 в двоичном виде 1 1111 1111, а нужно сохранить только первые 8 бит (1111 1111 = 255)

```
unsigned int i = 511;
i = i&0xFF;
unsigned char c = i;
```

В принципе, можно даже без `&0xFF`, если с `unsigned` типами. Но тут пусть уж гуру в стандартах скажут веское слово :)

Comment: Нужно еще учитывать порядок байт в системе.

Comment: @MGNeo Вы хотите сказать, что `i&0xFF` может дать не младший, а старший байт?... 8-\

Comment: @MGNeo Не нужно, результат от порядка байт не зависит. (Не уверен, что это гарантируется для signed типов, но это так на любой приличной реализации.)

Comment: Я имею в виду, что учитывать порядок байт нужно, если выполняется запись числа в файл. Обычно, когда число помещается в другую переменную, то говорят не `запись`, а `присвоение`. Это и ввело меня в заблуждение, я подумал, что запись осуществляется в файл, и я не смог найти в вопросе подтверждения или опровержения этого предположения.

Comment: Плюс, если знать порядок байт, то выполнить подсчет битов можно быстрее и экономичнее. Вместо того, чтобы использовать дополнительную переменную и лишнюю побитовую операцию, достаточно напрямую обратиться к младшему байту многобайтовой переменной. Низкоуровневая промышленная разработка дает о себе знать, извините...)